# Make grub run before Windows boot loader

Tags: grub2, mbr

I have installed Ubuntu next to Windows 7.
When I restart PC, MBR loads the Windows loader first then if I choose Linux, I have grub loaded.
My problem is that I would like Grub to be loaded first.

Comment: Is this a Wubi install? Because unless you installed `easyBCD` there's not normally any way that Windows boot manager is shown first.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, try `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`, replace `/dev/sda` if applicable.